# django sqlmigrate stuck in a buggy migration

Tags: python, django, migration

I have a small model for restaurants where I added an `item_image` attribute that receives url string. But instead of `CharField` I defined it as `IntegerField` . Then I ran `python manage.py makemigrations food` and `python manage.py sqlmigrate food 0002` . I gave an error

```
ValueError: Field 'item_image' expected a number but got 'https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/1377/1377194.png'.
```

I noticed the typo and fixed it( changed `IntegerField` to `CharField`).

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Item(models.Model):
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.item_name
    
    
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    item_desc = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    item_price = models.IntegerField()
    item_image = models.CharField(max_length=500,
                                  default='https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/1377/1377194.png')
```

but after I ran

```
python manage.py sqlmigrate food 0002
```

the error is still there and when I change it to

```
python manage.py sqlmigrate food 0003
```

and then run it. it gives no error but now for changes to take place I have to run

```
python manage.py migrate
```

which still gives the error on migration no.0002

How can I  ignore this migration?

Comment: `sqlmigrate` does *not* migrate, `sqlmigrate` only shows the query it will run to migrate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**`sqlmigrate`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/django-admin/#sqlmigrate) does *not* migrate, `sqlmigrate` only prints the (SQL) query it will run *when* you eventually migrate. This is thus more a debugging tool to see why the query does not work.

Since you did not (yet) run the `0002` migration on any database, since it would result in an error. You can just remove the migration (together with the `0003`), then run `makemigrations` again to create a *new* `0002` migration, and migrate.

Answer (score 0):

why are you trying 003? try just food, or the local host port 8000. if those dont work then try pyhton3 as your computer might be running a different python version and finds the image being the issue. maybe your format is not supported either. as in you don't have the necessary requirements for inputing and image. Im really not sure as i'm still learning Django myself but I hope this helps!

Comment: never mind that guy had a better answer than me haha.